# MySQL: Why does this select query not find row when joined table has multiple results?

Tags: mysql, join

Title might be confusing, didn't quite know how to put it. Here's what i need to do. I have two tables, cronjobs and cronjob_seeds. I need to see if a cronjob exists before adding it to the database.

Consider these tables:

cronjobs:

```
-id-   -callback_model-         -callback_method-
1       movie_suggestion_model    fetch_similar_movies
```

cronjob_seeds:

```
-cronjob_id-   -seed-
1               seed1
1               seed2
```

Before adding a new cronjob, i need to see if the exact same cronjob exists in the database. I wrote the following query, but it doesn't work if the cronjob has multiple seeds. It works good if it only has one seed, but every time a cronjob has multiple seeds it returns nothing.

```
SELECT `id`
FROM (`cronjobs`)
INNER JOIN `cronjob_seeds` ON `cronjob_seeds`.`cronjob_id` = `cronjobs`.`id`
WHERE `cronjobs`.`callback_model` = 'movie_suggestion_model'
    AND `cronjobs`.`callback_method` = 'fetch_similar_movies'
    AND `cronjob_seeds`.`seed` = '1'
    AND `cronjob_seeds`.`seed` = 10
```

Am i missing something? Should i be using another type of join?

And, off topic, but a seed is a parameter for the callback method, i just named it a little weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use IN clause

Change your query to:

```
SELECT `id`
FROM (`cronjobs`)
INNER JOIN `cronjob_seeds` ON `cronjob_seeds`.`cronjob_id` = `cronjobs`.`id`
WHERE `cronjobs`.`callback_model` = 'movie_suggestion_model'
    AND `cronjobs`.`callback_method` = 'fetch_similar_movies'
    AND `cronjob_seeds`.`seed` IN ('seed1', 'seed2')
```

Comment: I'll try your solution, give me a few mins.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, worked beautifully! Will accept in a few mins when i'm able to.

Comment: You can speed up this query slightly by using EXISTS:
`SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 'id...`

Answer (score 0):

Only to check if a cron entry exists, you don't need a join, unless you need to check if it exists and has specific seeds. To check only if a cron entry exists you need to do something like this:

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `cronjobs`
WHERE `cronjobs`.`callback_model` = 'movie_suggestion_model'
    AND `cronjobs`.`callback_method` = 'fetch_similar_movies'
```

Comment: I need to see if it has specific seeds.

Comment: @qwerty Then you should use Chandu suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

How come your query return result even when you had a single row for _cronjob_seeds_ . Cause the last two AND criteria conflict with each other. You should revise it as :

```
 AND `cronjob_seeds`.`seed` BETWEEN  '1' AND '10'
```

Also are you questioning the existance of a record in cronjob_seed or in cronjob? Your query parameters does not seem to be clear. Are you trying to check whether a specific cronjob with specific seeds exist? Tip: try to write the query in human language than sql